# Computing Bivariate normal CDF

Tags: probability

I am looking for more information about the ways to compute the CDF for a     bivariate normal distribution,
where to find the most accurate numerical tables !?
and whatever could help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find algorithms - and software implementations thereof - on the Web site of Alan Genz at Washington State University.  See:

http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/homepage